# What style is used in the background of this illustration?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, patterns

I'd like to recreate the white, black and red background used in this poster. I prefer using Illustrator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Draw a red and brown triangle shape as shown below (to the right). Group them, and in the Appearance panel, apply a transform effect as shown.

[image]

Add a cream coloured rectangle for the background to cover the entire page, and send to back. Draw another rectangle on top just inside the page boundary, then select the transformed object and the top rectangle. Click Object > Clipping Mask > Make.

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly same as yours but this tutorial will help you imho: http://projectwoman.com/2014/01/multicolor-sunburst-in-illustrator.html

Here's an example:
[image: sun burst effect]

Comment: Please don't just post a link--links rot with horrifying speed these days. Please consider posting an excerpt (in your own words because of copyright) of the technique presented in the site you link to. That way your answer is still valid and of use when the link does rot. Thanks!